# Learning JavaScript Promises just need some direction

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am Learning JavaScript Promises and I just wanted to know if the following code is correct.  Basically it's very simple. Loads a script file.  If the file can't be loaded there there is a error.

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  var fh = document.createElement('script');
  fh.type = 'text/javascript';
  fh.async = true;
  fh.src = 'script.js';

  /*Insert javascript at top of dom */
  fhs.parentNode.insertBefore(fh, fhs);


  /*Success Response */
  fh.addEventListener('load', function (event) {

    resolve('Loaded');

  }, false);


  /*Error Response */
  fh.addEventListener("error", function (event) {

    reject(Error('Error loading file'));

  }, false);
});
```

Comment: I don't know how the DOM's event listeners work, but the basic premise looks correct. But this question doesn't fit in SO. Please use codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I would add the event listeners before adding the node to the DOM - probably doesn't make any different ... maybe

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you run this code and test it?  That will tell you whether it's correct or not.  We can't answer your question if you don't have a clear, concrete problem.

Comment: What is the actual error message you're getting?

Comment: @thefourtheye, code review is for code without errors; working code. As this is not that, it does not belong there.

Comment: @Quill True, Do you see any possible errors in this code as such? Anyway, I may be wrong in suggesting that.

Comment: If the code does not work as intended; it is off-topic for Code Review. Although the code does seem to be missing something needed to solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't know codereview.stackexchange.com existed.  I will use this feature next time.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

```
fhs.parentNode.insertBefore(fh, fhs);
```

`fhs` is not defined. Where is it supposed to come from? The console would have caught this error for you. Instead, you can append the script element to the body.

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  var fh = document.createElement('script');
  fh.async = true;
  fh.src = 'script.js';

  /*Insert javascript at bottom of dom */
  document.body.appendChild(fh);  

  /*Success Response */
  fh.addEventListener('load', () => resolve('Loaded'));

  /*Error Response */
  fh.addEventListener("error", () => reject(Error('Error loading file')));

});
```